# How to share a file in Android programmatically

Tags: android, share

I want to share a file(.pdf,.apk etc) using share Intent, I searched google but I find only the code for sharing Image

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You use the same code, you just change the MIME type for the type of data you wish to share.  If you wish to share anything regardless of type, use `*/*`

Answer (score 11):

To keep your code pragmatic, use `ShareCompat` class:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setStream(uri)
        .setType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName()))
        .startChooser();
```

Comment: ShareCompat.IntentBuilder' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Comment: IntentBuilder.from() is deprecated use IntentBuilder()

Answer (score 3):

This will help you

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

Comment: By using this as-is, you will get `FileUriExposedException` when targeting SDK 24 >. Instead, you should be using a `FileProvider` instead of passing the `Uri` directly.

Comment: for this exception FileUriExposedException add this code in your main activity under onCreate method.   StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ShareFile(String path)
{
    Intent shareToneIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareToneIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
    shareToneIntent.setType(GetMimeType(Uri.parse(path)));
    requireContext().startActivity(shareToneIntent);
}

public String GetMimeType(Uri uri) {
    String mimeType = null;

    if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        mimeType = requireContext().getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    } else {
        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension.toLowerCase());
    }
    return mimeType;
}
```